# PowerShell script to manage the Azure DevOps Permission i.e Asigning Readers permission to users using API

Tags: powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to use the below three apis to assign permission to set of user as a reader.

**1.** Get All Users
GET Request
[https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organisation}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.3](https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/%7Borganisation%7D/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.3)
-- using this api I am trying to retrieve the id property of every user and store it in an
array to use.
**2.**
Get All Groups
GET Request
[https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organisation](https://vssps.dev.azure.com/%7Borganisation) name}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=7.1-preview.1
This api gives me all the groups within the organisation later on I apply filter in script to only look for Readers groups
**3.**
[https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organisation}/_apis/GroupEntitlements/xxxxxx42fd-bbe6-0507682fxxx/members/xxxx-0dbc-4568-b823-xxxxxxx?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/%7Borganisation%7D/_apis/GroupEntitlements/xxxxxx42fd-bbe6-0507682fxxx/members/xxxx-0dbc-4568-b823-xxxxxxx?api-version=6.0-preview.1)

The third api is used to apply the put request to assign the readers permission.
Can someone help me with the scrip that can be used for this?
Below is my half script in which I am trying to build up the logic.

```
$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organisation}/"

$pat = "kjbkcbkbkbkcbksbkjbskvbkvbkbvkjbkjbkxxxxxxxxxx"
#Get a list of all the groupid from organisation
$groupsUrl = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{org name}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$usersUrl =   "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{org name}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.3"

$AddReader =    "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{org name} /_apis/GroupEntitlements/kdnkjsncnjkbjkbk-sdjncd-bdjckc-kjdb/members/ksckjkjkj-sde31e0720d69?api-version=6.0-preview.1"

$groupidarray = @()
$useridarray  = @()

# Demo users to grant access
$demoUsers = @("sachintendulkar@yhi.com,a-haadkjc.singh@yhi.com")

# Get the id of all group and retrieve originID

$groupsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $groupsUrl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $([Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$pat")))"} 
$readersGroup =$groupsResponse.value | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq "Readers"} 
#Write-Host "$readersGroup"
$groupidarray = $readersGroup.originId 
Write-Output $groupidarray


$usersResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $usersUrl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $([Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$pat")))"}
$readersUser =$usersResponse.members.user | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq "Sachin Tendulkar"} | convertTo-Json
Write-Host "$readersUser"
$useridarray = $readersUser.originId
Write-Output $useridarray
```

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

From your requirement, you need to use PowerShell script to run rest api to add the target users in array to all Readers Groups in the Organization.

> Can someone help me with the scrip that can be used for this?

I have used the same Rest APIs as yours to write the PowerShell script.

Try the following sample:

```
$token = "PAT"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$demoUsers = "emailaddress1", "emailaddress2"


foreach ($user in $demoUsers) {
  
    echo $user

    $GetUserID="https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.3"

    $listusers = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetUserID -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

    foreach ($userinfo in $listusers.members) 
    {
       if($userinfo.user.mailAddress -eq $user)
       {
           $userid= $userinfo.id

           $Getgroups ="https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

           $listgroups = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Getgroups -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

           foreach ($groupinfo in $listgroups.value) 
           { 
              if($groupinfo.displayName -eq "Readers")
              {
                $groupid= $groupinfo.originId

                $AddUser="https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/GroupEntitlements/$($groupid)/members/$($userid)?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

                $Adduserresult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $AddUser -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method PUT -ContentType application/json
              }
           }
       }
       
    }
    
}
```

This script will loop the users in the array and loop the groups in the organization. Then it will automatically add the users to the Readers group one by one.